# how to remove Ì from data in C

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, parsing

I am getting a value like this

```
"RE000022000500200Ì 0.00 0.1 0.129.8#####-  97-   2#####-   1#####   960.504.00 0: 00.000.00 8: 013:52 0: 021:52############2.00.0   "
```

I want a value like this after doing some processing on above data can you You please what should be the logic to remove "Ì"

```
"RE000022000500200 0.00 0.1 0.129.8#####-  97-   2#####-   1#####   960.504.00 0: 00.000.00 8: 013:52 0: 021:52############2.00.0   "
```

Comment: i removed null by checking for '\0' but dont have any idea of how to remove "Ì"

Comment: Please, paste the source code.

Comment: "I am getting" from where? how? what did you do? what did you try? why is this tagged as both, C and C++?

Comment: It would help if you gave some context as to what the Ì represents: Is it an error? Is it always in a fixed place or is it operating as a seperator? Posting your efforts so far will help contributers to assess what you're trying to do and therefore they will be better placed to help you.

Comment: Your question is about the logic. The logic is simple enough, you have to copy the characters after the first 'Ì' backwards one character. Similarly all characters after the second 'Ì' have to be copied backwards two characters etc. etc. Do this and you'll end up with the same string but with all 'Ì' removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy enough if you are using `std::string` to hold your value.

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

std::string input = ...;
input.erase(std::remove(input.begin(), input.end(), 'Ì'), input.end());
```

It's more complex if you insist on using C strings or arrays.

I see from the comments above that you are using C strings. I suggest you switch to using C++ strings.

Comment: I don't think that will work, `'Ì'` is 0xC3 0xAC in UTF-8. http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ec/index.htm

Comment: @jrok: We don't even know if the OP is using UTF8 or anything else, or if he even has to change a string, for what we know it could be a problem printfing a buffer with garbage data...

Comment: @jrok I hadn't thought of that. I suspect uninitialised data however as PlasmaHH says. Unfortunately if the OP won't post some code, then he's not going to get much useful help.

Answer (score 2):

If there's no character that's value is 0xC3 in your data, you can traverse your data string, if an character that it's value equals 0xC3 occur, then remove the character and the next character.